# WSO2 APIM Clustering Configuration

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 APIM 1.10.0 on a single server deployment and would like to move to a clustering one. Looking at [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0) documentation I could found a lot of information, howevre something is boring me; do I really have to always do all of it?

I mean, I don't want to split all my workers in multiple instances, all I want is configure two full setup configurations (key manager + publisher + store + gateway), each one on its own host and make sure I can put a load balance in front of it.

Thre requiremenst are simple: I would like to share the load on both of them, and guarantee a better availability in case of one of the hosts goes down. Is it a MUST break down the whole installation on both nodes so I have to start each component independently with offset ports configured?

I coud see that on version 2.0.0 a lot have been simplified, any way to reach the same on 1.10.0 one?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Splitting into profiles is not mandatory. This is designed in this way to scale API Manager based on the TPS. If you have a low TPS count and prefer to have 2 node HA setup, you can do the following.

- Cluster the two nodes using wka, aws, etc.
- Use dep-sync to share API artifacts between two nodes.
- Use one node as the Publisher. You need to handle the publisher node traffic using single node. This is to avoid getting SVN conflicts.
- You can serve API requests from both nodes.

Comment: It took me sometime to figure out how to put everything in cluster, now that I did it I could understand that your awser had some sense. I finish it, and something curious is that I can use any node as publisher/store once I put the rsync to synchronize data from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to always use the same deployment pattern mentioned in the docuemtnation that you have pointed [there](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0). There are various Other deployment patterns that you can use according to the scalability and the requirement of yours. 
Please refer the following documentation [1] for different deployment patterns you can use for WSO2 API Manager and [2] for more information on worker Manager separation and Load balancing.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/API+Manager+Deployment+Patterns

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Separating+the+Worker+and+Manager+Nodes